# Searching in all fields, case insensitive, and not analyzed

Tags: elasticsearch

In elasticSearch, 
How can I define a dynamic default mapping for any field (the fields are not predefined) that is searchable with spaces and case insensitive values.

For example, if i have two documents:

```
PUT myindex/mytype/1
{
  "transaction": "test"
}
```

and

```
PUT myindex/mytype/2
{
  "transaction": "test SPACE"
}
```

I'd like to perform the following queries:

```
Querying: "test", Expected result: "test"
Querying: "test space", Expected result "test SPACE"
```

I've tried to use:

```
PUT myindex
{
 "settings":{
     "index":{
        "analysis":{
           "analyzer":{
              "analyzer_keyword":{
                 "tokenizer":"keyword",
                 "filter":"lowercase"
              }
           }
        }
     }
  },
  "mappings":{
     "test":{
        "properties":{
           "title":{
              "analyzer":"analyzer_keyword",
              "type":"string"
           }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

But it gives me both document as result when looking for "test".

Comment: Can you also show the exact query you're making? Make sure to use a `term` query and not a `match`

Comment: Another thing you need to make sure is that you're creating documents with the `mytype` mapping type, but your mapping definition is named `test`.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there was a mistake running my query:
Here's a solution I found to this problem, when using multi field query:

```
#any field mapping - not analyzed and case insensitive
PUT /test_index
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "analyzer_keyword": {
            "tokenizer": "keyword",
            "filter": ["lowercase"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
        "dynamic_templates": [
            { "notanalyzed": {
                  "match_mapping_type": "string",
                  "mapping": {
                      "type":        "string",
                      "analyzer":"analyzer_keyword" 
                  }
               }
            }
          ]
       }
   }
}


#index test data
POST /test_index/doc/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":3}}
{"name":"Company Solutions", "a" : "a1"}
{"index":{"_id":4}}
{"name":"Company", "a" : "a2"}


#search for document with name “company” and a “a1”
POST /test_index/doc/_search
{
  "query" : {
    "filtered" : {
      "filter": {
        "and": {
          "filters": [
            {
              "query": {
                "match": {
                  "name": "company"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "query": {
                "match": {
                  "a": "a2"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```